# ng model in html with dropdowns with ngx-translate library angular 4/5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dropdown, ngx-translate

I am looking for a solution to covert the dropdown using ngx-translate.

Basically, I was trying to do following using ng-model.

For example. localhost:4200/volvo/insert it should take value from route params as volvo and display the selected as a volvo on the dropdown.

same as localhost:4200/saab/edit it should take value from route params as saab and display the selected default as a saab on the dropdown.

I do have following code without ngx-translate.

When I insert the ngx-translate. The selected function is not working in the drop-down.

```js
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    routeType: string;

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
       // router.url will give you /volvo/insert so you can split it and choose the 2nd instance of its resulting array
       this.routeType = this.router.url.split('/')[1];    // volvo
    }

}
```

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="routeType">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please provide the code that doesn't work. Code that works will not help us to understand the problem.

Comment: I have added the example code. Basically, I was trying to do following using ng-model.For example.

localhost:4200/volvo/insert

it should take value from route params as volvo and display the selected as a volvo on the dropdown.

same as

localhost:4200/saab/edit

it should take value from route params as saab and display the selected default as a saab on the dropdown.

Comment: How do you add the ngx-translate?

Comment: I have added using translate pipe. For example; {{'volvo.title' | translate}}